# many belongs_to and has_many in single line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Hi I am working on one application which has so many relations on the model. 
Now I am thinking to reduce line of code and I find so many relations like `has_many` and `belongs_to`.

Can we have singe line where we can write something like

`belongs_to [:comment, :rating, :indication], dependent: :destroy`

`belongs_to :travels, foreign_key: travel_item_id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, not. AFAIK this is not possible and even the documentation doesn't seems to allow this.
What you can do, is to define a metaprogramming method that iterate over an array and create this associations. But not sure if it worth it.

**EDIT**

Just an example of what I mean by `metaprogramming method`
Create a file `app/models/concerns/associate.rb`

```
module Associate
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def associate(ass_type, names = [], params = {})
      names.each do |n|
        send ass_type, n, params
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then, in your model, to do the multiple `belongs_to`, just do

```
include Associate
associate :belongs_to, [:comment, :rating, :indication], dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: Yes . Thats what I have done exactly when you said metaprograming.
Thanks a lot for the detailed answer . It really helped me.